# How do I press <Primary><Shift><Alt>Right, what does it do, and where in the GUI is this keyboard shortcut recorded?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

On my Xubuntu 20.04 machine, `~/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-keyboard-shortcuts.xml` lists `<property name="<Primary><Shift><Alt>Right" type="string" value="move_window_right_key"/>` as one of my keyboard shortcuts. Despite this, I can neither find this shortcut in the Keyboard menu's 'Application shortcuts' list nor in the Window Manager's 'Keyboard' list. This gives me three questions:

1. How do I press `<Primary><Shift><Alt>Right`?
2. How is `"move_window_right_key"` distinct from the `tile_right_key` command that is mapped to Super + Right by default?
3. Where is this keyboard shortcut recorded in the GUI?

I suspect that `<Primary>` is Left Ctrl, but this combo does nothing to my windows.

Comment: Very confusing question. Maybe reword it?

Comment: @David I think the confusion is down to the weird way that Xfce lays outs its keyboard shortcuts. I don't think there's anything that I can do to make this more clear.